# Error while integrating DocuSignSDK - Undefined Symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_*

Tags: ios, cocoapods, docusignapi, podspec

## Missing Symbols - DocuSignSDK

After following the steps to integrate DocuSign Native iOS SDK via Cocoapods as per  https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk. Getting the following errors when building my sample app.

Tried `pod install` after removing all files under `Pods/*` and `Podfile.lock`, this doesn't resolve the issue.

Error:

- Undefined symbol:

  - _OBJC_CLASS_$_DSMEnvelopesManager, _OBJC_CLASS_$_DSMManager, _DSM_SETUP_TRUE_VALUE and other symbols

[image: DocuSign Native iOS SDK - Undefined symbol]

Answer (score 2):

## Root cause

This issue occurs because of `DocuSignSDK.Framework/DocuSign` binary isn't getting fetched correctly via the CocoaPods `pod install`. Correct DocuSignSDK binary is over `100MB`, for example, the correct binary size as of `v2.2.5` is `105.8MB`. In projects with `symbol missing` issue, the binary size is a few KB.

[image: DocuSignSDK - Binary]

## Ensure Client is fetching DocuSignSDK Binary

- Close Xcode
- Go to the solution direction and perform `pod deintegrate` to uninitialize the pods.
- `rm Podfile.lock`
- `rm -rf Pods/`
- Make sure `Podfile` has a correct entry for a beta branch, e.g.:

  - pod 'DocuSign', :git => 'https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk.git', :branch => "beta/responsive-online-signing"
- `pod install` or `pod install --repo-update`
- Ensure `DocuSignSDK.framework/DocuSignSDK` binary file is available and is around `~105MBs`
- Open workspace and build